# Write a data variable to binary file in python

Tags: python, matlab, file, binaryfiles, fwrite

In Matlab/Octave we have this command to save a variable to binary file:

```
a = fwrite(myfile, uint16(x), "uint16");
```

I would like to know is there any equivalent command in Python?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I think it could be a solution

```
import numpy as np

a = myfile.write(np.uint16(x));
```